# JavaFX 2 Titlebar color

Tags: javafx-2

How can I change the color of the title bar in javafx 2 desktop app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area of the window there title is written is controlled by OS. OS manages it's color, active/passive state, close-minimize buttons, etc. and FX has no API to handle that.

You may opt to create your own titlebar by using `Stage` with `StageStyle.UNDECORATED` and draw any decoration you like for such window.